# How to modify the label output in cleveref and varioref?

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref

EDIT: The mentioned solution on the bottom of this page works perfectly for the label output. But now I am struggling with the distance of the \crefname and the counter. Instead of a space I would like to have a smaller distance between fig. and the number. Instead of fig.~1 I'd like to have fig\,1 but it appears that I am losing myself in the code of the cref manual.

I am using a combination of `varioref`, `cleveref` and `hyperref` to use a - I would say - more "sophisticated" referencing behaviour. It enables me to simply use `\vref{labelname}` to get the output

> Table 1 on page 1

My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%Kodierung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%%Kodierung
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}%language
\usepackage[format=plain,indention=1em,labelfont=bf,font=footnotesize,justification=justified,position=bottom]{caption}  %schönere Captions durch den \caption-Befehl

%%%%%%%%%%
%REFERENCES
%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}  
\usepackage[linktocpage=true,bookmarksopen,hidelinks,ngerman,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%Hyperrefpaket    
\usepackage[ngerman,nameinlink,sort]{cleveref}

\renewcommand*babel\reftextfaraway[1]{auf S.\,\pageref{#1}}%
\addto\extrasngerman{\renewcommand{\reftextfaraway}[1]{auf S.\,\pageref{#1}}} %Short page labels


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{table}
\caption{Text}
\label{text}
\end{table}

\newpage

\vref{text}

\end{document}
```

Now, what I want is: I would like to change the way the Table or Figure or whatever is named in the text, when I use a 'ref' command. Instead of

> Figure 1 on page 1

I would like to get (preferably in German but I guess this is reached by a general trigger or babel)

> Fig. 1 on p. 1

Through research I already figured out how to modify the label in the float itself by adding this code (since I am using the babel package this is needed):

```
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}}
```

Also, in a forum I found a way to modify the pagelabel output but I failed at changing the text output of my referencing command. I tried

```
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\crefname}{Abb.}}
```

But, this simply gives me an error of a missing control sequence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed in [the `cleveref` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) (page 12), use (don't redefine) the `\crefname` and `\Crefname` macros:

```
\addto\captionsngerman{
    % Second argument is singular, third is plural
    \crefname{figure}{abb.}{abb.}
    \Crefname{figure}{Abb.}{Abb.}
}
```

Comment: Damn, under section 7.1.2. How couldn't I find it? Thanks. Now I would like to change the space between the label and the counter to "\," instead of "~". In the manual I only can find how to change the space for \crefrange. I am quite lost with the \crefdefaultlabelformat. I cannot see a way to modify spaces with this command. Do you know how to accomplish this -- most probably simpliest -- task?

Comment: You can only do this with the low-level formatting commands \crefformat etc. See section 7.2 of the manual for details.